# How does anacron start in Centos7?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, cron

**How does anacron start in Centos7 ?**

/etc/crontab shows empty

- anacron.conf contains cron.daily folder
- cron.daily folder contains **logrotate** config file
- logrotates are working perfectly

My question : I cannot find any relation between **cron and anacron** then how does anacron start in centos7 .

Answer (score 3):

It's run from cron, of course, using the script in `/etc/cron.hourly/0anacron`.

Scripts in `/etc/cron.hourly` are run hourly by the job in `/etc/cron.d/0hourly`.

Comment: thanks, But /etc/crontab  is empty and cron.hourly ! not include

Comment: If it really was not there, then anacron wouldn't run.

Comment: Yes it was not there ...   cat /etc/crontab
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

Comment: What are you talking about? I didn't say anything about `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: cron.hourly not include /etc/crontab then how  cron.hourly  and 0anacron work .. sorry for my poor English

Comment: cron executes all crontabs from `/etc/cron.d/`. Hence, it picks up `/etc/cron.d/0hourly` calling `run-parts /etc/cron.hourly`

Answer (score 1):

`anacron` and `cron` are similar but different tools.  They are both daemons, and normally you will install one or the other.  They will each handle their own scheduled workload.  If both are installed, neither should ever execute the others commands if both are installed.

`cron` is the older tool and designed for systems that are always on (servers).  Newer versions will execute commands listed in `/etc/crontab`.  It is is possible to create crontab entries to run the `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly` and `/etc/cron.monthly` workload if anacron is not installed.

`anacron` is a newer tool better suited for systems that are not always on.  It uses the file `/etc/anacrontab` to control what should be run.

Comment: Unlike `cron`, `anacron` is not a daemon. It's a binary, which on CentOS gets executed hourly by ... `cron`.